# Jquery doesn't show response

Tags: jquery

I'm using this script in drag & drop file upload system, and it works just fine except for the fact it won't show me the file name. Here's the code

```
$(function () {
    var dropbox = $('#dropbox'),
        message = $('.message', dropbox),
        template = "";
    dropbox.filedrop({
        paramname: 'pic',
        maxfiles: 5,
        maxfilesize: 50,
        url: 'post_file.php',
        uploadFinished: function (i, file, response) {
            $.data(file).addClass('done');
        },
        error: function (err, file) {
            switch (err) {
            case 'BrowserNotSupported':
                showMessage('Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
                break;
            case 'TooManyFiles':
                alert('Too many files! Please select 5 at most!');
                break;
            case 'FileTooLarge':
                alert(file.name + ' is too large! Please upload files up to 50mb.');
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        },
        uploadStarted: function (i, file, len) {
            createImage(file);
        },
        progressUpdated: function (i, file, progress) {
            $.data(file).find('.progress').width(progress);
        }
    });

    function gName(file) {
        template = '<div class="preview">' +
            '<p>' + file.name + '</p>' +
            '</span>' +
            '<div class="progressHolder">' +
            '<div class="progress"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
    }

    function createImage(file) {
        var preview = $(template);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        message.hide();
        preview.appendTo(dropbox);
        $.data(file, preview);
    }

    function showMessage(msg) {
        message.html(msg);
    }
});
```

If I run `alert(file.name)` within `createImage` function, it will grab it for me, however the template simply isn't added to the page at all. This is pretty much the only way I can define the template without getting an error for it, but it will not display it. If I change the template to something like

```
var template = '<div class="preview">'+
'<span class="imageHolder">'+
'<img />'+
'<span class="uploaded"></span>'+
'</span>'+
'<div class="progressHolder">'+
'<div class="progress"></div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>';
```

It works just fine, but I can't access `file.name` within that variable, and that's really all I need.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you defined it outside or inside of that function in the first place personally...

Comment: @NicholasHazel bottom piece of code represents it working, if defined outside a specific `function fN(file)` is what I mean, where I can't access `file.name`. If I move template variable inside a specific `function fN(file)` to grab `file.name`, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: If you create a variable inside a function, it is limited to the scope of that function (at least in theory, block coding). By using `var` you're keeping it relative to the `scope` of the block it's wrapped in.

Comment: @kcdwayne yup but if I use it outside a function (replace `gName` function with the `var template`) I can't print `file.name`.

Comment: But your gName function doesn't actually return anything. If it had `return(template)`, it might :)

Comment: @kcdwayne added `return (template);` at the end of it, still doesn't seem to work =)

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? From what I see, you're passing (or at least attempting to) a load of HTML as if it were a jQuery object.

Comment: @kcdwayne I'm trying to show the file name, by passing that load of HTML! It's a modified version of this: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

Comment: @SamFisher Alright, I gotcha. The passing HTML as object threw me lol. Check my answer, fiddle included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I see what you're trying to do.

```
var template = '<div class="preview">' +
    '<p>' + file.name + '</p>' +
    '</span>' +
    '<div class="progressHolder">' +
    '<div class="progress"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

What you'll want to do is specify (or create) an object, then use `.append()` to add your `template`.

```
$('#dropbox').append(template);
```

This will add your `template` right before the closing tag of `#dropbox`

*You shouldn't have to wrap a single variable in a function. As long as `file` is in the same scope (or an inner level of the level it's on) **and** above the call for it, this will work just fine.*

If you do feel so inclined to wrap it in a function, `return(thevariable)` so it isn't just sitting there ;)

Faddle with my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4k9q8/)?

Comment: I'm actually trying to roll this update you posted but I'm failing. I'm not sure how to fiddle it for you since this is way too big. If you do visit the tutzine link I posted, I really want that one without thumbnails and with file names instead literally. I don't have `file` in a scope where I can nest `var template` from what I can tell.. Bah I wish there was a way to show you all this

Comment: Just a sec might have figured it out

Comment: I looked through the link you provided. It looks like `file` is created in the dropbox source (I don't really want to read through their entire code), but it *looks like* the `reader` function grabs the image source via `e.target.result`.  You might be able to do something below it by 1st defining `var theURL = e.target.result`, then append that with whatever markup you like. You could even make it "pretty" by dropping the extention and spacing/capitalizing the file name.

Comment: So I defined a `var thisname = null;` and I did this: `function gName(file) { thisname = file.name; return(thisname); }` just to call it as `thisname` inside the template. Best result I got so far, it will show me null but at least it shows something.

Comment: All it's returning is the `null` from outside the function. You really don't have to wrap it in a function... just sayin. Pretty print URL: http://jsfiddle.net/4k9q8/1/

Comment: DONE MAN! After 3 days, I wish I could buy you a beer man I swear

Comment: Example of variable passing: http://jsfiddle.net/4k9q8/2/
The problem is, file.name just isn't there to be anything. It, too, is null in this aspect.

Comment: Congrats :) Glad I could help. Good luck!